# Mounting NTFS External Drive with Bit Locker

Tags: mount

I am a complete novice to Ubuntu/Linux.

How do I mount an USB powered external NTFS drive? I've installed both Mount Manager and NTFS Configuration Tool. 
This drive is encrypted having used Windows Bit Locker. I know the password.

Comment: I dont think linux supports bitlocker..

Answer (score 2):

BitLocker is not supported by the Linux NTFS driver, you will need to copy the data to a plain NTFS partition.

Comment: Could I copy that data from my external drive to another partition on my main hard drive?

Comment: Using Windows, yes